# SQL Server How to modify this query to match a specific value with v1.Id in the ProductAttributeCombination.AttributeXml column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I modify this query to work as expected?

I want "@ID="       "" this value to be match with v1.Id.

ProductAttributeCombination.AttributeXml is (nvarchar(Max), null)

```
CAST(c1.AttributesXml AS XML).exist('/Attributes/ProductAttribute[@ID=sql:variable("@v1Id") and ProductAttributeValue/Value[. = sql:variable("@v1Id") ]') = 1
```

From

```
SELECT 
p.Id, 
p.Sku, 
p.[Name], 
v1.[Name] AS Color, 
v2.[Name] AS Size
 , c1.StockQuantity
FROM  Product p
INNER JOIN Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m1 ON m1.ProductId = p.Id AND p.Deleted = '0' 
INNER JOIN Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m2 ON m2.ProductId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN ProductAttribute a1 ON a1.Id = m1.ProductAttributeId AND a1.[Name] = 'Color'
INNER JOIN ProductAttribute a2 ON a2.Id = m2.ProductAttributeId AND a2.[Name] = 'Size'
INNER JOIN ProductAttributeValue v1 ON v1.ProductAttributeMappingId = m1.Id
INNER JOIN ProductAttributeValue v2 ON v2.ProductAttributeMappingId = m2.Id
  INNER JOIN ProductAttributeCombination c1 ON c1.ProductId = p.Id 
        AND CAST(c1.AttributesXml AS XML).exist('/Attributes/ProductAttribute[@ID=sql:variable("@v1Id") and ProductAttributeValue/Value[. = sql:variable("@v1Id") ]') = 1
```

Example of AttributeXml attriubte

```
<Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>112</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>115</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
```

ProductAttribute ID is same as ProductAttribute_Mapping.Id and ProductAttributeValue ID is same as ProductAttributeValue.Id

No error, no results. I get results when not use ProductAttributeCombination c1.

This is the results of query I provide in the beginning without c1.StockQuantity.

```
Id  Sku             Name            Color         Size
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK           S
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED             S
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     S
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre             S
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK           M
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED             M
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     M
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre             M
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK           L
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED             L
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     L
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre             L
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK           S
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED             S
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK     S
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK           M
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED             M
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK     M
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK           L
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED             L
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK     L
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED             S
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK           S
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     S
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED             M
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK           M
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     M
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED             L
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK           L
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE     L
```

There are so many results for ProductAttributeCombination, this is part of the results.

First two numbers are for the Color and last two numbers are for the Size.
ProductAttribute ID in the AttributeXml should "=" to  Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping.Id, and ProductAttributeValue should "=" to ProductAttributeValue.Id.

```
Id  ProductId   AttributesXml                                   
1169    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>112</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>115</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1170    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>112</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>116</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1171    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>112</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>117</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1172    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>113</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>115</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1173    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>113</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>116</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1174    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>113</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>117</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1175    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>114</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>115</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1176    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>114</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>116</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1177    63  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>114</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>117</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1145    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>102</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>104</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1146    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>102</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>105</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1147    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>102</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>106</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1148    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>103</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>104</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1149    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>103</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>105</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1150    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>103</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>106</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1160    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>108</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>104</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1161    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>108</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>105</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
1162    58  <Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="49"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>108</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="50"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>106</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? My current guess is SQL Server..

Comment: It is SQL Server

Comment: The `.value` method is used for XML data type.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, The .value method is used for XML data type.

Try casting it:

```
 SELECT 
p.Id, 
p.Sku, 
p.[Name], 
v1.[Name] AS Color, 
v2.[Name] AS Size,
c1.StockQuantity
FROM  Product p
INNER JOIN Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m1 ON m1.ProductId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m2 ON m2.ProductId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN ProductAttribute a1 ON a1.Id = m1.ProductAttributeId AND a1.[Name] = 'Color'
INNER JOIN ProductAttribute a2 ON a2.Id = m2.ProductAttributeId AND a2.[Name] = 'Size'
INNER JOIN ProductAttributeValue v1 ON v1.ProductAttributeMappingId = m1.Id
INNER JOIN ProductAttributeValue v2 ON v2.ProductAttributeMappingId = m2.Id
INNER JOIN ProductAttributeCombination c1 ON c1.ProductId = p.Id 
WHERE p.Deleted = '0'
AND CAST(c1.AttributesXml AS XML).exist('/Attributes/ProductAttribute[@ID=sql:variable("@v1Id") and ProductAttributeValue/Value[. = sql:variable("@v1Id") ]') = 1
```

[CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thank you. But am i using the right value for  "('(/Attributes/ProductAttribute[@ID="       "]/@Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') "? It doesn't look like a Example of AttributeXml attriubte "<Attributes><ProductAttribute ID="59"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>112</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute><ProductAttribute ID="60"><ProductAttributeValue><Value>115</Value></ProductAttributeValue></ProductAttribute></Attributes>
"

Comment: Thank you sir, could you check my revised query after edit?

Comment: describe the error in the post

Comment: I edit my post and no return results. What other information should I provide for clarification?

Comment: Thank you. Could you check the edit post again? ProductAttribute ID is same as ProductAttribute_Mapping.Id and ProductAttributeValue ID is same as ProductAttributeValue.Id in AttributesXml value. So could you make two CAST, one for the Size and one for the color.

Comment: @non It would help if you give the *actual* XML rather than keep changing the goalposts. I think you can do the whole thing in one big `exist` call as show in this answer, you don't need to use `.value` and you don't need multiple calls

Comment: Hello, I just update my post. How can I use EXIST for "ProductAttribute ID in the AttributeXml should "=" to Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping.Id, and ProductAttributeValue should "=" to ProductAttributeValue.Id" ?